# how to display array element-by-element in specific format in matlab

Tags: matlab, formatting

I am using matlab sprintf to print numbers stored in 1D array with specific format. For example, I have two array A=[1 2 3], B=[4 5 6], I expect it to print as

```
1/4; 2/5; 3/6
```

I try the following command

```
p=[1 2 3];
q=[4 5 6];
sprintf('%d/%d; ', p, q)
```

But it gave me

```
1/2; 3/4; 5/6
```

Any way to work it around? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p=[1 2 3];
q=[4 5 6];
sprintf('%d/%d; ', [p; q])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change display `format rat`:

```
format rat
A = [1 2 3];
B = [4 5 6];
```

And in the command window

```
A./B
ans =
       1/4            2/5            1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i=1:n
sprintf('%d/%d;', p[i], q[i])`